# Subclassing TableViewCell, backgroundView and selectedBackgroundView mystifying me

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

I'm subclassing UITableViewCell and using Quartz 2D to draw the elements of the cells in the drawContent view method.  In my table view delegate's tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath, I'm also inserting a UIImageView as a subview to the cell, but the image doesn't appear until the cell is selected.  I'm suspicious of the backgroundView and selectedBackground view here, but I'm not sure what I can do to ensure the image is always visible.  Here's what it looks like when then cell is selected...

[alt text http://www.irovr.com/stackoverflow/tableviewcell.png](http://www.irovr.com/stackoverflow/tableviewcell.png)

I want it to also look this way when the cell isn't selected, but it currently appears as black.  My table view background color is black.  The cell's background is clear.

Comment: I would like to see your code for tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  I was adding the image to the overall table cell view.  I had to add a new view property to my subclass and insert it at the 0 index.  Otherwise, the superclass was laying out the views the way it was designed to and interfered with my image.

Comment: You need to check mark this answer so that the system shows the question as answered. You can answer your own questions.